# How to split array of strings into sub-arrays according to special starting character?

Tags: python, ruby

Can you simplify this code from Python into Ruby? Lets say I have this data

```
data = ['hello', 'person', ';hello', 'otherperson']
print([x.split("@") for x in "@".join(data).split(";")])
```

When I print it it prints this:

```
[['hello', 'person', ''], ['hello', 'otherperson']]
```

Is there something like this in Ruby? If it can be accomplished in one line, I would prefer that, but I'm after just knowing how it is.

Comment: Do you need the empty string `''` in the first array? It seems to be a side-effect of processing.

Comment: @NeilSlater you are right, it's just an effect I do not need it thanks for asking.

Comment: What are you doing anyway?!

Comment: I'm creating a IRC like project that manages a connection to chats through TCPSockets and of the "events" that has useful data is like that pattern, I wanted to separate the data so I can use it later on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Literally translated,

```
data.join(?@).split(?;).map { |x| x.split(?@) }
```

But you might want a different approach entirely. This will misbehave if any of the strings contain `@`.

Answer (score 1):

This works for intended output, but do note it modifies original strings, so ideally `data` is a deep clone (or otherwise not a problem to alter contained strings):

```
data.slice_before { |s| s.gsub!(/^;/,'') }.to_a
 => [["hello", "person"], ["hello", "otherperson"]]
```